How to retrieve specific data using cURL
I am attempting to retrieve either of the "SeatCount" values from the JSON below. The problem I'm having is that the endpoint requires authentication but the site is setup for SSO using a corporate account. All attempts to send user/password crendentials fail. Assuming I can get past the authentication issue, is there a way to "scrape" for the data?
{
"_links": {
"parent": {
"href": "/internal/account",
"type": "application/json"
},
"self": {
"href": "/internal/billingv2/account/subscription",
"type": "application/json"
}
},
"planType": "Enterprise",
"version": 1,
"trialStartDate": "2020-11-09T13:49:58.743Z",
"trialEndDate": "2020-12-23T13:49:58.743Z",
"trialExtensionCount": 0,
"campaigns": {
},
"usagePeriodStartDate": "2024-10-01T00:00:00Z",
"usagePeriodEndDate": "2024-11-01T00:00:00Z",
"billingProcess": "StandardBilling",
"state": "ActiveSubscription",
"_limits": {
"EventsPublished": 0,
"EventsReceived": 0,
"ExperimentationKeys": 10000,
"MonthlyActiveUsers": 1000000,
"SeatCount": 200
},
"_mongoLimits": {
"EventsPublished": 0,
"EventsReceived": 0,
"ExperimentationKeys": 10000,
"MonthlyActiveUsers": 1000000,
"SeatCount": 200
},
"_hasCustomLimits": false,
"primaryContextKind": "user"
}

